# Social Network Activity Feed + Groups

Tags: database, android-activity, social-networking, feed

I'm working on an social network app and want to create an activity feed so people can keep up to date with all of their connections (classic facebook stream).  I have a DB table called `activity` setup for this like so:

```
activity_id (int)
user_id (int)       //who posted it
group_id (int)      //the group of connections that have permission to view
type (enum)         //the type of activity performed
time (datetime)     //the time the activity was performed
```

I would then do a `select * from activity where user_id in (connections)` to get the latest news.

Here's the catch. User's activities do not always have visibility to the complete set of connections. Users can create groups of user ids to form smaller sets within their super set of connections. Its like how facebook allows you to specify who sees a particular post instead of allowing all friends to see it.

I have a separate `groups` table setup with the following schema:

```
group_id (int)
connection_id (user_id, int)
user_id (group creator)
```

I have a group_id in my activity table. The group_id is the link to the subset of connections that have permission to see the post.

My question is, what is the best way to do this type of feed, and is there an optimal single select statement that will get me the output desired (a list of my connections activities that I have been granted permission to see)?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: I shelved the project for a bit so I stopped hunting. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to offloading your activity stream functionality to a service via an API, Collabinate (http://www.collabinate.com) may be useful to you.